# Server fails to start due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, log4j, build.gradle, web.xml

I'm trying to start my tomcat server but it fails and gives me

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener]
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/SetUtils
```

I'm using gradle and I have

```
dependencies{
...
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.12.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.12.2'
...
}
```

I have `Log4jServletContextListener` configued in web.xml as

```
...
    <context-param>
        <param-name>isLog4jAutoInitializationDisabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
...
```

Here is the complete error

```
12-Nov-2022 13:11:37.918 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
12-Nov-2022 13:11:37.981 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener]
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/SetUtils
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.getConfigURI(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:196)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.initializeNonJndi(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jWebInitializerImpl.start(Log4jWebInitializerImpl.java:112)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener.contextInitialized(Log4jServletContextListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.SetUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 17 more
```

Not sure how to resolve this error

Comment: I think you are missing that library in your project that's why that exception occured.

Comment: Try to add that library manually to your project

Comment: BTW: version 2.12.2 has some serious security vulnerabilities (cf. Log4Shell). You should use the latest version available (2.19.0) if possible or 2.12.4 if you are stuck on Java 7.

Comment: is adding 
```implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:2.12.2'``` in dependencies different from adding the library?